# Shallow cloning and deep cloning

Tags: java, cloning

I am revisiting some of the fundamental aspects of Java and have some doubts regarding shallow cloning and deep cloning. I know them in details and aware of the internals. But I stumbled on this simple exercise -

Department class -

```
public class Department {
    String deptName;

    public String getdName() {
        return deptName;
    }

    public void setdName(String dName) {
        this.deptName = dName;
    }

    public Department() {
        super();
    }

    public Department(String dName) {
        super();
        this.deptName = dName;
    }
}
```

Employee class -

```
public class Employee implements Cloneable{
    int empNo;
    String empName;
    Department dept;

    public int getEmpNo() {
        return empNo;
    }
    public void setEmpNo(int empNo) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
    }
    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }
    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }
    public Department getDept() {
        return dept;
    }
    public void setDept(Department dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }
    public Employee(int empNo, String empName, Department dept) {
        super();
        this.empNo = empNo;
        this.empName = empName;
        this.dept = dept;
    }
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

The main class -

```
public class ShalowCopyTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Department dept1 = new Department("Development");
        Department dept2 = new Department("Testing");
        Employee emp1 = new Employee(10, "Peter", dept1);
        Employee emp2 = null;
        try {
            emp2 = (Employee) emp1.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(emp1.getDept().getdName());
        System.out.println(emp2.getDept().getdName());

        System.out.println("Now changing emp1.dept");
        //emp1.setDept(dept2); //This is deep cloning - why?
        emp1.getDept().setdName("Testing"); //This is shallow cloning
        System.out.println(emp1.getDept().getdName());
        System.out.println(emp2.getDept().getdName());
    }
}
```

You can see that if I use emp1.setDept(dept2), changing the dept of emp1 has no effect on emp2. So this is deep cloning. But changing the dName by just emp1.getDept().setdName("Testing") is making the dName change for emp2 as well. So this is shallow cloning. Why these two lines are making a difference? Why they are not the same?
Thanks.

Comment: You are sort of comparing apples and oranges here IMO.  Both lines should cause something to "stick."  In the first case, you updated the department, and in the second, you updated the name.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, thanks! The question is if I directly change the name of the original dept, then that original reference is updated. In that case it is not creating another copy and making the change there, it's just updating the original and that is impacting both emp1 and emp2. But if I change the dept as a whole, then it is making another copy of the dept and assigning it to the clone. So why in this case it is creating another dept reference? Which part of the code is telling to do like that? If you see setDept() method, I am using this.dept=dept -> means shallow cloning!

Comment: I am not using new() to create a new dept and later modify it! Neither I am using any copy constructor anywhere. So everything is shallow. But this.dept=dept is creating a new reference and that's my question. Is it intended behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you are using same example as on this link: [A Guide to Object Cloning in Java](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/)

Probably you already know that the default implementation of super.clone() does a Shallow Copy instead of a Deep Copy.

In this case, both object instances: emp1 and emp2 will contain references that points to the same places in memory.
Referring to Department instances, this is how it references in memory after emp1 object is cloned:
[image]
Both refer to the same place in memory, that contains an immutable String: "Development".

By setting:

```
emp1.setDept(dept2);
```

it changes the reference of emp1 to the new object dept2:
[image]

In this case you will see it as a Deep Copy but in fact is not. It is just that the emp1 changed it's reference to a new place in memory.

In the other case, when you set:

```
emp1.getDept().setdName("Testing");
```

You will change the Departman's name to "Testing" - which will be visible to both object instances.

Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Hi @Luisa Bradusca, thanks for your message. Yes, I understand that in both the cases it is shallow copying, but only when I am doing emp1.setDept(dept2), the references point at different locations. This issue can be reproduced even with copy constructor.

`Line1: System.out.println(orig.getDept()==copy1.getDept()); //True after cloning or copy constructor
Case1: orig.setDept(dept2);
Case2: orig.getDept().setdName("Testing");
Line2: System.out.println(orig.getDept()==copy1.getDept());`

You will see in Case1, Line2 will give false, but for Case2, Line2 will give true.

Comment: So this is my main question, before orig.setDept(dept2), the dept references of both orig and copy were pointing to the same location. But after orig.setDept(dept2) they detached and started pointing to different locations. But even after orig.getDept().setdName("Testing"), they are still pointing to the same location! What is fundamentally different in these two setps? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @NirmalyaSinha, Case 1: Step 1) Make a clone. Step 2) set:  orig.setDept(dept2). After this, orig.getDept() != copy1.getDept(), because, as you also said, they detach the departments references and point to different locations. Case 2: Step 1) Make a clone. Step 2) set: orig.getDept().setdName("Testing"). After this, orig.getDept() == copy1.getDept(), because after cloning, they both refer to same object and orig.getDept().setdName("Testing") changes the name of the department that both objects refer to.

Comment: Case 3: Step 1) Make a clone. Step 2) set orig.setDept(dept2). Step 3) orig.getDept().setdName("Testing"). After this, orig.getDept() != copy1.getDept(), because at Step 2) the object references have detached and at Step 3) the name attribute for instance dept2 was changed, not the original one. I hope now it is clear what is happening.

Comment: So in Case 2 after orig.getDept().setdName("Testing"), why the dept references of orig and copy didn't get detach like Case 1? This is the main point I am talking about.

Comment: In Case 2 the 'name' attribute of Department gets detached, not the department itself. At first, the name of the department had the value "Development" and after the statement: orig.getDept().setdName("Testing") the referenced changed to a new location that has the value "Testing". It is the same as Case 1 but it is for the name attribute within the Department.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a shallow and now a deep copy, it only seems like you have a deep copy. Let me try to explain why:

The object you are cloning (Employee) does have a complex datatype (Department). If you clone an object that contains other objects then you only copy the reference and not the actual object.

Let’s take a look at your code:

```
emp1.setDept(dept2)
```

In this case you are not altering the actual instance (which would have an impact on both, the clone and the original), but you are assigning a new object to the `dept` instance of `emp1`. Therefore you now have different instances of `dept` in `emp1` and `emp2`. That is why it seems like you have a deep copy.

Let’s say you would have another instance variable inside of your Department with all the necessary methods:

```
public class Department {
    String deptName;
    int someNumber;

    public void setNumber(int number){
    someNumber=number;
    }

    public int getNumber(){
    return someNumber
    }


    public Department(String dName, int number){
    super();
    deptName = dName;
    someNumber = number;
    }
    }
```

In you main Method you do something like that:

```
Department dept1 = new Department(“Development”, 50);
Employee emp1 = new Employee(10, “Peter”, dept1);
Employee emp2 = null;
emp2 = (Employee) emp1.clone();
System.out.println(emp1.getDept().getNumber; // Output: 50
System.out.println(emp1.getDept().getNumber; // Output: 50
//Now we change the instance variable of dep1 inside emp1
emp1.getDept().setNumber(100);
//Now print the numbers of both employees again
System.out.println(emp1.getDept().getNumber; // Output: 100
System.out.println(emp1.getDept().getNumber; // Output: 100
```

As you can see, it is a shallow and not a deep copy.
The only reason why `emp1.getDept().setdName(“Testing”)` is just altering the original and not the clone is because Strings are immutable. Every time you change a String you get a new String instance back, therefore it doesn’t have any impact on the original String instance after cloning the object.

To make your example a deep copy you have to adjust your clone method like so:
(I made some small adjustments as well so the datatype is matching and you don’t need a try/catch anymore)

```
@Override
public Employee clone(){
Employee clone = null;

try{
clone = (Employee)super.clone();
clone.Department = Department.clone(); // This is the important line!! You need to clone the Department Object aswell. 
}catch (CloneNotSupportedException e){
e.printStackTrace();
    }
return clone;
}
```

Of course you have to implement the clonable Interface and the clone method inside if your Department Class aswell to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `super.clone()` and `super` is an `Object`, you get a shallow clone in which every field gets copied.

So if you start with:

emp1 -> dept1 -> dname1

then `emp2 = emp2.clone()`, you get:

emp1 -> dept1 -> dname1
            ^ 
   emp2 ----/

i.e. they are both pointing at the same `Department` object.

If you then do `dept1.name = dname2`, you only affect dept1, so you get:

emp1 -> dept1 -> dname2
            ^ 
   emp2 ----/

... and `emp1.getDepartment().name = dname2` has exactly the same effect -- it doesn't matter how you get at the object.

If you now do `emp2.department = dept2`, it does not affect emp1, so you end up with:

emp1 -> dept1 -> ... // unchanged
   emp2 -> dept2 -> ... // newly assigned

To get deep cloning you would need to write your own clone routine, which clone each level.

This is easy to get wrong. Better to get in the habit of using immutable objects, in which shallow copies "just work" -- because you can never change a field, you can't accidentally affect an object that's sharing the same object as the one you're working with.